# Can anyone help me decipher this diagram?

Tags: general-topology

[Theorem with Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxQPz.png)
Can anyone help me with this diagram?

Comment: Arrows represent inclusions and $f, g$. The diagram isn't really important.

Comment: Arrows (**here**, not always) denote (continuous) functions. Diagrams are a way of clearly organising your thoughts about what is mapping to what

Answer (score 1):

The regular arrows represent the continuous functions $f: X \to Y $ and $g:A \to B$.

The other arrows, such as $A \rightarrowtail X$ seem to represent subset inclusion. It might specifically mean $A$ is open subset of $X$, but it's not clear from the image alone.